# Embedded video inside of Android media player

Tags: android, html, html5-video, android-mediaplayer, android-video-player

I have an application that I want to play a video in. I want to play the video from an embed code via html5 in an iframe. Is it possible to call the androids stock video player to play the video from the iframe embed code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by putting my embed code in an html file inside the assets folder. works greate.